# is there a way to programmatically check that generated typescript Prisma client is up to date with the schema.prisma file?

Tags: node.js, prisma

as per title.

The reason I ask is because in development I often forget to generate it when I pull changes from remote and then I am dumbfounded as to why my app is not working.
This would save me a lot of unnecessary trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have worked around this problem by creating a custom prisma generator here: https://github.com/capaj/prisma-generator-checker

but it sure would be nice if prisma client could check this by default at runtime or at least if prisma stored the schema hash in the generated client so that we can perform this check at runtime ourselves without the need for a custom generator.